# Check if there are list elements different from character(0)

Tags: database, r, loops, sql-update

I have a function to update the database for a list of ID (max 1,000 elements at once, for `IN` in Oracle DB):

```
## Split the data frame into chunks of 1,000 elements max.
chunk <- split(df, ceiling(seq_along(df$id) / 1000))

res <- lapply(chunk,
  function (x) sqlQuery(database,
                        paste0(
   "UPDATE sometable
    SET flag = '", batch.id, "'\n  ",
   "WHERE id IN (", paste0("'", x$id, "'", collapse=", "), ")")))
```

I'd like to test that my updates went well. But I did not find a way to get the count of updated rows via `rODBC` calls.

Thus, as a (satisfying!?) workaround, I'm looking at the text results of `sqlQuery`, and understand that when everything goes well, I get a list of `character(0)` results.

Now, how to assert that all the `UPDATE` queries were correctly done?

I tried using `any` or `all` calls, with no success:

```
> all(res == character(0))
[1] TRUE
> all(res != character(0))
[1] TRUE

> any(res != character(0))
[1] FALSE
> any(res == character(0))
[1] FALSE
```

I don't understand that, whatever my condition, the result is always `TRUE` (for `all`) or `FALSE` (for `any`).

Tried `all.equal` with no more success:

```
> all.equal(character(0), res)
[1] "Modes: character, list" "Lengths: 0, 1" "names for current but not for target" "target is character, current is list"
```

Comment: you have to `lapply` over res.

Answer (score 0):

you have to `lapply` over res.   as in `lapply(res, identical, character(0L))`

Comment: I'm left with a list... In an `if`condition, do I have to use `all` then?  I tried `all(lapply(sortie.update.all, identical, character(0L)))` and got: 
    [1] TRUE
    Warning message:
    In all(lapply(sortie.update.all, identical, character(0L))) :
      coercing argument of type 'list' to logical

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
all(vapply(res,length,1L)==0)
```

This evaluates the length of each component of res and returns `TRUE` if all the elements are of zero length (as `character(0)` is).

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Try `0==0L`.

Comment: I meant the "1" to be replaced by "0", that is: `all(vapply(res,length,0L)==0)`

Comment: @user3341592 See `?vapply`. The last argument is a prototype of the returning value of `FUN` on a single element of `X`. Since `length` returns a length one `int`, I provided a length one `int` (like `1L`). Of course your option works too. `all(vapply(res,length,7777L)==0)` also works as well as `all(vapply(res,length,integer(1))==0)`.